# signup GUI with steps

Tags: android, user-interface

I am working on a signup GUI and the process of signup include two steps (hence, two "screens").
Would you create two activities for that cause? or would you manipulate the UI in order to give that impression?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont prefer manipulating the UI. It will unnecessarily clutter the code. So better you can go with multiple activities or fragments with a smooth transition.

Also check about ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you can approach this. You can make two activities and use `putExtra()` to send data between them. You can also use fragments to have different parts of the form appear when you need them.